# How to log specific HTTP header using logback.xml

Tags: logback

I would like to create a console appender that displays some log info, and also prints out a particular http header, similar to this:

```
> [INFO] { "time": "2017-08-31 12:14:32,583", "app-id": "my-app", "my-header": "my-header-value" } -- "Hello, World"
```

I have created a `logback-spring.xml` file like below, but "my-header" just prints out blank.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

<springProperty name="appId" source="spring.app.application_id"/>

<!-- Appender to log to console -->
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <!-- Minimum logging level to be presented in the console logs-->
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            %clr(%5p) %clr({ "time": "%date{ISO8601}", "app-id": "${appId}", "my-header": "%X{my-header}"}){faint} -- %msg%n
        </pattern>
        <charset>utf8</charset>
    </encoder>
</appender>
​
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

I have read that using `logback-access` gives you access to HTTP request/response properties, but when I try setting the encoder class I cannot use any of the classic logback conversion words:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

<!-- Appender to log to console -->
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <!-- Minimum logging level to be presented in the console logs-->
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.access.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern class="ch.qos.logback.access.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            %clr(%5p) %clr({ "time": "%date{ISO8601}", "app-id": "${appId}", "my-header": "%header{my-header}"}){faint} -- %msg%n
        </pattern>
        <charset>utf8</charset>
    </encoder>
</appender>
​
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

The logback above gives these errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project pd-thundera-server: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Logback configuration error detected:
[ERROR] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@4782f0a4 - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [p]
[ERROR] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@4782f0a4 - [p] is not a valid conversion word
[ERROR] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@6071227e - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [msg]
[ERROR] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@6071227e - [msg] is not a valid conversion word
```

How can I access a request header?

Comment: how did u solve it

Comment: Where does `springProperty` come from? It is not part of Logback?!

Comment: The `springProperty` is Spring Boot's extension to Logback.
[Reference doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#_environment_properties)

Answer (score 4):

This configuration worked for me:

```
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>%t{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %h X-Forwarded-For: %header{X-Forwarded-For} "%r", Response status:%s, Bytes sent:%b, Response time:%D</pattern>
    </encoder>
```

Name of the header goes in between curly braces, e.g. `%header{Content-type}` or `%header{My-header}`, or just `%header` if you want all headers to be logged.

Source:

- https://logback.qos.ch/access.html#configuration
- https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#AccessPatternLayout

Comment: @Billa not sure what else i could add, expanded answer slightly and added reference to documentation

Answer (score 0):

Please find below example with Spring

If you want to log http headers then you need to use MDC feature: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

create Filter:

```
@Component
class RequestHeaderFilterConfig : Filter {

    private val xRequestId = "X-Request-Id"

    override fun doFilter(request: ServletRequest?, response: ServletResponse?, chain: FilterChain?) {
        val httpRequest = request as HttpServletRequest
        MDC.put(xRequestId, httpRequest.getHeader(xRequestId))
        chain?.doFilter(request, response)
    }

    override fun destroy() = MDC.remove(xRequestId)
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping
    fun operation(@RequestHeader(value = "X-Request-Id", required = false) xRequestId: String? = null): ResponseEntity<Output> {
        ....
    }
```

logback.xml

```
<Pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level [X-Request-Id: %X{X-Request-Id}] %logger{36}.%M:%line - %msg%n</Pattern>
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@eranda/mapped-diagnostic-context-mdc-b6c81ff426f1